# Running a batch file in a network directory using VBA

Tags: excel, batch-file, vba

I have a .bat file calling from VBA, it is working when I use a local folder as path (example as C:\Users\cthoud01\Desktop\my scripts\scripts).

However, I got an error if I use a path from a network directory (example - H:\scripts). I also tried replacing the path as """H:\scripts\""" but continue to get the same error. I would like to hear from our experts if there is any way around to make this work.

Below is the error message I receive:
[image]

VBA Code I am using:

```
Sub test()
Dim wsh As Object
Set wsh = VBA.CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
Dim waitOnReturn As Boolean: waitOnReturn = True
Dim WindowStyle As Integer: WindowStyle = 1
Dim errorCode As Long


Dim pth As String
errorCode = wsh.Run("cmd.exe /k cd """ & "H:\scripts\" & """ && DeleteMatrix.bat", WindowStyle, waitOnReturn)

If errorCode <> 0 Then
    MsgBox "fail, please retry"
    End
End If
```

End Sub

Comment: See `cd /?` for why it doesn't work. Your `cd` command isn't doing what you think it is.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
errorCode = wsh.Run("cmd.exe /k cd /d """ & "H:\scripts\" & """ && DeleteMatrix.bat", WindowStyle, waitOnReturn)
```

Look at the extra `/d`.

In MSDos each drive had a current directory.

```
C:\>cd D:\dog
C:\>Copy *.* D:
```

would copy files into the d:\dog directory. This makes typing easier. There were no mouses or menus.

Windows only has the concept of current directory (and it's per program).

So MSDos batch files run unchanged in CMD you have to tell windows you don't want MSDos behaviour with the CD command by using `/d`.

Likewise CMD simulates a default drive per directory.

This is what it looks like in the process's environment block

```
=C:=C:\Users\David Candy\Desktop\Editor\EditorSdi
=D:=d:\~MSSETUP.T
```

Comment: Awesome, thanks, this works with both local and network folders.

Comment: Is that `/d` switch relatively new?  (i.e. added some time in the last 10 years?)  I don't remember that ever being available when I was using DOS commands many years ago.

Comment: There are two Windows' versions of CMD. NT4 and earlier and Windows 2000 and later. It was developed on OS/2. It was originally CP/M compatible, Microsoft added Unix features (concept of handles and redirection) in MSDos V2, IBM OS/2 made it work identical to MSDos but overloaded most of the commands with lots of extra features so it's a hodge podge. MS was very VAX/VMS orientated when it arrived on Windows but it's very close to IBM's version. In Help all references to new behaviour are referring to NT4 to Win 2000 not MSDos to CMD.

Comment: @user6017774 I am getting "CMD does not support UNC path as current directories" error if I use a network shared drive, is there any work arround for that? Thinking to use PUSHD command but quite not sure how to integrate with this.